# Find Products with No Images

Tags: magento-1.7, product

Is it possible to run a query to find a list of products with no images assigned to them? Ideally I'd like SKUs printed out on the screen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can find the collection for below code.

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image',
            'like' => 'no_selection'
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // null fields
            'null' => true
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // empty, but not null
            'eq' => ''
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // check for information that doesn't conform to Magento's formatting
            'nlike' => '%/%/%'
        ),
    ));
```

you can got all product list which has no Images assign.

Answer (score 10):

If you want only the products that don't have `image`, `small_image` or `thumbnail` assigned then the answers from @KeyulShah or @TBIInfotech will give you just that.

If you want the products that have no images at all, you can run this query on the database and get them.

```
SELECT
    e.sku, COUNT(m.value) as cnt
FROM
    catalog_product_entity e 
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery m
        ON e.entity_id = m.entity_id
GROUP BY
    e.entity_id
HAVING
    cnt = 0
```

If you remove the `having` statement you will get a 2 column result with the product skus and the number of images assigned to them.

You can just export that as a csv.

Comment: By any chance Will it work in Magento2 !

Comment: probably, but I cannot guarantee it

Answer (score 5):

Just a small modification to what @keyul shah described, just put the code on magento root:

```
<?php 

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image',
            'like' => 'no_selection'
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // null fields
            'null' => true
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // empty, but not null
            'eq' => ''
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // check for information that doesn't conform to Magento's formatting
            'nlike' => '%/%/%'
        ),
    ));

foreach($_products as $_product){

    echo $_product->getSku();

}
```

Comment: Your solution worked great, I've given you an upvote but will award the answer to the original post.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone looking for Magento 2. This will work.
Its same as @Marius just added one table.

```
SELECT 
     e.sku, COUNT(m.value) as cnt
FROM catalog_product_entity e
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity r
    ON e.entity_id = r.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery m
    ON r.value_id = m.value_id

GROUP BY
    e.entity_id
HAVING
    cnt = 0
```

Comment: I ended up writing something based on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344922/70343

Answer (score 2):

This works for me....

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'small_image',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'thumbnail',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'small_image',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'thumbnail',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            )
        ),
        null,
        'left'
    );
```

Comment: This works better, because if the product has not image yet, probably the attribute relation doesn't exists, and probably wont work correctly.