# Identify All products with Images not showing on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, image-upload

I currently have a store with quite a few broken images, I need a list of all the products on the store which do not have working images,

I believe that the reason is because the products are referencing images that do not exist on the Server,

Is there a way I can export a list of all these products, so I can then find the images that I need and fix this issue,

going through this manually will take endless time with the amount of products on the website

Answer (score 0):

Following thread can help you.

[Find Products with No Images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23991/find-products-with-no-images)

You can filter collection as per given code.

Then you can print product names or SKUs in loop as follows.

```
foreach($_products as $_product)
{
    echo $_product->getSku().'<br/>';
}
```