# How to get a list of all products without images in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, media-images

Is there a way of seeing a list of all the visible products on the fronted that do not have images linked to them.

Comment: Yes. Where you want to display it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back and built a FREE module that retrieves a filterable list of all the products without images on the backend.

Link: https://github.com/dacodmagagula/Magento2-MissingProductImagesReport

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of scenarios on two different projects. Missing media where entries were in the database but not in file system due to data loss via migration. This needed a clean up.

But also then I had a scenario where I needed to know products that were missing media which then needed to be filtered by enabled SKUs.

My commands are here:

https://github.com/DominicWatts/MissingMedia

The code for products that have no gallery entries is here

https://github.com/DominicWatts/MissingMedia/blob/master/Console/Command/Missing.php#L239-L318

```
    /**
     * get status attribute ID
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStatusAttributeId()
    {
        $ea = $this->resource->getTableName('eav_attribute');
        $eet = $this->resource->getTableName('eav_entity_type');
        $select = $this->connection->select()->from(
            ['ea' => $ea],
            ['ea.attribute_id']
        )->joinLeft(
            ['eet' => $eet],
            'ea.entity_type_id = eet.entity_type_id',
            ['']
        )->where(
            'ea.attribute_code =?',
            ProductAttributeInterface::CODE_STATUS
        )->where(
            'eet.entity_type_code =?',
            ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE
        );


        $data = $this->connection->fetchOne($select);
        return (int) $data ?? null;
    }


    /**
     * Find products with no media entries
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProductsWithNoMedia($enabledOnly = false)
    {
        $cpe = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity');
        $cpemg = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery');
        $cpemgvte = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity');
        $select = $this->connection->select()->from(
            ['cpe' => $cpe],
            ['cpe.sku', 'cpe.entity_id', 'cpe.type_id']
        )->joinLeft(
            ['cpemgvte' => $cpemgvte],
            'cpe.entity_id = cpemgvte.entity_id',
            ['']
        )->joinLeft(
            ['cpemg' => $cpemg],
            'cpemgvte.value_id = cpemg.value_id',
            ['count' => 'count(cpemg.value)']
        )->group(
            'cpe.entity_id'
        )->having(
            'count = 0'
        )->order(
            'cpe.type_id',
            SortOrder::SORT_ASC
        )->order(
            'cpe.sku',
            SortOrder::SORT_ASC
        );


        if ($enabledOnly == true) {
            $cpei = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int');
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['cpei' => $cpei],
                'cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id',
                ['']
            )->where(
                'cpei.attribute_id = ?',
                $this->getStatusAttributeId()
            )->where(
                'cpei.store_id = ?',
                Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            )->where(
                'cpei.value = ?',
                Status::STATUS_ENABLED
            );
        }


        $data = $this->connection->fetchAll($select);
        return $data ?? [];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('image', 'no_selection');

foreach($products as $product)
{
    echo  $product->getSku();
}
```